# What are .first and .return when applied to subs?

Tags: raku

I found the operator `andthen` somewhere, and when I looked it up in https://docs.raku.org/routine/andthen I found this:

```
#!/bin/env raku
sub load-data
{
  rand  > .5 or return; # simulated load data failure; return Nil
  (rand > .3 ?? 'error' !! 'good data') xx 10 # our loaded data 
}

load-data.first: /good/ andthen say "$_ is good";
# OUTPUT: «(good data is good)␤» 

load-data() andthen .return; # return loaded data, if it's defined 
die "Failed to load data!!";
```

So, how do `.first` and `.return` work when applied to subs ?
I've never seen such things before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So, how do `.first` and `.return` work when applied to subs ?

It doesn't. You're not calling `.first` *or* `.return` on a `Sub` object.

When a subroutine in Raku appears with no arguments, it's called. So simply writing `load-data` on its own *calls* `load-data`, as though you'd put parentheses. (Note: If you *want* to get the subroutine object itself, you use an `&` sigil, so `&load-data` is the subroutine object) So this

```
load-data.first: /good/ andthen say "$_ is good";
```

is equivalent to something like this in a more familiar Python-like syntax.

```
load_data().first("good") and say(...)
```

First, `load-data` is called. It returns either `Nil` or a list of data. Now [`first`](https://docs.raku.org/type/List#routine_first) is called on the list.

> Returns the first item of the list which smartmatches against `$matcher`, returns `Nil` when no values match. The optional named parameter `:end` indicates that the search should be from the end of the list, rather than from the start.

You've called it as `load-data.first: /good/`, so it will return the first element of the list for which the regular expression `/good/` matches, or `Nil` otherwise.

[`andthen`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/andthen) is like `&&`, except that while `&&` checks for truthiness (via a Boolean context), `andthen` checks for definedness via the multi method [`defined`](https://docs.raku.org/routine/defined). Objects like `Nil` and failures are undefined, while most "ordinary" objects like numbers and strings are defined. In particular, things that are conventionally "falsy" like zero or the empty string are still defined. Like `&&`, `andthen` short-circuits, so if the left-hand side is undefined, then the right-hand side never evaluates.

Finally, there's one other quirk that enables this line to work. `andthen` is designed to work with this exact use case: Do thing 1 and, if that thing succeeds, do thing 2. Frequently, thing 2 depends on the result of thing 1. So `andthen` assigns the result of the left-hand side to the special variable `$_` during evaluation of the right-hand side. That's a mouthful, so let's write it out. `x andthen y` does the following.

1. Evaluate `x`.
2. If `x` is not defined, then stop. We're done. Return `x`.
3. Otherwise, set `$_` to the result of `x`.
4. Now evaluate `y` (with `$_` set) and return it.

So, taking it all in...

```
load-data.first: /good/ andthen say "$_ is good";
```

Load the data, find the first element of the loaded data which matches a regex, and if one exists, then print it out.

Now let's take a look at your second example. There's another fun little piece of syntax sugar you need to know about for this one. In general, a dot at the beginning of a statement carries an implied `$_`. So `.say` is equivalent to `$_.say`, which is equivalent to `say($_:)`, which evaluates after method resolution to `say($_)`.

And believe it or not, [`return`](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/return) is a subroutine. Seriously. It's not a keyword; it's a sub. Go evaluate `&return.WHAT` in your REPL right now. It'll say `(Sub)`.

```
load-data() andthen .return;
die "Failed to load data!!";
```

`load-data` gets called, and if it returns anything defined, that defined value gets assigned to `$_`. Then `.return` happens, which is equivalent to `$_.return` which (eventually) becomes `return($_)`. If the value was defined, it gets returned from the function and the second line never runs. If not, we `die` with an appropriate error message.

Note that the parentheses are actually required in this case. If we write

```
load-data andthen .return;
```

Then Raku tries to interpret `andthen .return` as an *argument* to `load-data` and complains that no subroutine called `andthen` exists. It thinks we meant

```
load-data(andthen(.return));
```

In summary, Raku is a big bag full of syntax sugar wrapped in a parser from the sixth circle of Hell that's whitespace- and context- sensitive, and the result is a genuinely beautiful language.